# Ghost Blog: Issues Updating Node Version

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-22.04, ghost-blog

I am attempting to update the Node version to the latest supported version at the time of writing; **v18**. I have followed the instructions exactly step by step. However, despite this, it installed **v20.9.0** instead and I can't find a way to downgrade it to the supported **v18** so I can go ahead with the the Ghost updates.

I am running Ghost on an **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** server.

It's really strange as well because although when running the command `node -v` it displays that I have managed to upgrade it to **v18**. However, as you can see in the screenshot below when I try to the run `ghost update`, I get the following error message.

[image]

I followed the instructions on the official documentation here: https://ghost.org/docs/faq/node-versions/

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to admit that a while ago i ran into similar issues. The number one thing is to ensure you are running a supported LTS version of `nodejs`.

In my case i didnt and also dont run Ghost on recommended Ubuntu but on CentOS stream.

I'll write/paste below my actions, you'll want to convert them to the Ubuntu/dpkg equivalent.

## Cleanup

```
dnf module list nodejs

Last metadata expiration check: 1:40:38 ago on Sun 19 Nov 2023 09:08:06 AM CET.
CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream
Name                                Stream                              Profiles
nodejs                              18                                  common [d], development, minimal, s2i
nodejs                              20 [e]                              common [d], development, minimal, s2i

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

As you can see i have the wrong versions enabled

```
yum remove nodejs
dnf module reset nodejs
```

## Install

```
dnf module enable nodejs:18

yum install nodejs
Last metadata expiration check: 1:45:13 ago on Sun 19 Nov 2023 09:08:06 AM CET.
Dependencies resolved.
Installing:
 nodejs                                    x86_64                          1:18.14.2-2.module_el9+307+7e5e4074
```

I got a warning about an npm update, which didnt want to install, but thats 'fine' with me for now :)

### Install ghost

`npm install ghost-cli@latest -g`

## Ghost blog

Be sure to be the `web-user` whichever you use and be in the ghostblog websites path

```
/usr/local/bin/ghost check-update
/usr/local/bin/ghost backup
/usr/local/bin/ghost update

# Downloading and updating Ghost to v5.74.0
```

And its all done.